# AD not returning the groups which authenticated user belong to

Tags: vb.net, active-directory, ldap

I'm able to authenticate given user - Domain, UserName and Password with LDAP but not able to retrive his groups which he associated with :(

Here the code i'm using

```
Public Function ValidateActiveDirectoryLogin(ByVal domainName As String, ByVal userName As String, ByVal userPassword As String) As Boolean
        Dim isValidated As Boolean = False

    Try

        Dim ldapPath As String = "LDAP://" & domainName
        Dim dirEntry As New DirectoryEntry(ldapPath, userName, userPassword, AuthenticationTypes.Secure)
        Dim dirSearcher As New DirectorySearcher(dirEntry)

        dirSearcher.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" & userName & ")"
        dirSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf")

        Dim result As SearchResult = dirSearcher.FindOne()

        If Not result Is Nothing Then

                For Each x As DictionaryEntry In result.Properties
                    x.Key.ToString()

                    'DirectCast(x, System.Collections.DictionaryEntry).Key()
                Next

                Dim groupCount As Integer = result.Properties("memberOf").Count
                Dim isInGroup As Boolean = False

                For index As Integer = 0 To groupCount - 1
                    Dim groupDN As String = result.Properties("memberOf").Item(index).ToString

                    Dim equalsIndex As Integer = groupDN.IndexOf("=")
                    Dim commaIndex As Integer = groupDN.IndexOf(",")

                    Dim group As String = groupDN.Substring((equalsIndex + 1), (commaIndex - equalsIndex) - 1).ToLower
                    If group.Equals(groupName.ToLower) Then
                        isInGroup = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next index

                isValidated = isInGroup
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception(ex.Message)
    End Try

    Return isValidated

End Function
```

Please help...

Venky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way I will use, sorry it's code I translate from C# to VB.Net

```
` Connection to Active Directory
Dim deBase As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://192.168.183.100:389/dc=dom,dc=fr", "jpb", "pwd")

` Directory Search for the group your are interested in
Dim dsLookForGrp As DirectorySearcher = New DirectorySearcher(deBase)
dsLookForGrp.Filter = String.Format("(cn={0})", "yourgroup")
dsLookForGrp.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree
dsLookForGrp.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName")
Dim srcGrp As SearchResult = dsLookForGrp.FindOne

If (Not (srcGrp) Is Nothing) Then
    Dim dsLookForUsers As DirectorySearcher = New DirectorySearcher(deBase)
    dsLookForUsers.Filter = String.Format("(&(objectCategory=person)(memberOf={0}))", srcGrp.Properties("distinguishedName")(0))
    dsLookForUsers.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree
    dsLookForUsers.PropertiesToLoad.Add("objectSid")
    dsLookForUsers.PropertiesToLoad.Add("userPrincipalName  ")
    dsLookForUsers.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sAMAccountName")
    Dim srcLstUsers As SearchResultCollection = dsLookForUsers.FindAll
    For Each sruser As SearchResult In srcLstUsers
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", sruser.Path)
        ` Here Test if you username is insode 
        Console.WriteLine(""& vbTab&"{0} : {1} ", "sAMAccountName", sruser.Properties("sAMAccountName")(0))
    Next
End If
```

Be careful the primary group is given by the `primaryGroupID` and it's not a DN but an ID which is the lasr part of the group SID.

Last thing, But you can also do it using [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx). Here is a sample in C#

```
/* Retreiving a principal context
 */
Console.WriteLine("Retreiving a principal context");
PrincipalContext domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "WM2008R2ENT:389", "dc=dom,dc=fr", "jpb", "PWD");


/* Look for all the groups a user belongs to
 */
UserPrincipal aUser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainContext, "user1");
PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> a =  aUser.GetAuthorizationGroups();

foreach (GroupPrincipal gTmp in a)
{
  Console.WriteLine(gTmp.Name);    
}
```